# Windows Boot Manager didn't come up as indicated in the instructions

Tags: dual-boot, windows-xp

I'm not technical.  I installed Ubuntu using the Wubi installer.  When I pressed 'finish' to restart, the Windows Boot Manager did NOT come up.  My computer just rebooted in Windows.  How do I get to this Windows Boot Manager so I can switch operating systems?  I'm using Windows XP, by the way.

Comment: Did Wubi display any error message? What instructions did you follow?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Comment: that's the instructions and it went as described.  ticked reboot now pressed finish, no errors just computer rebooted as if nothing happened.  no boot manager as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Install EasyBCD for Windows and add an Ubuntu boot entry, should work fine then.

Comment: OK just googled that thanks I will try tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: OK just got home and downloaded from CNet and it tells me it need Vista/7 bootsomething or other and that it won't work in XP environment.  The puter I want to do this on is running XP as I mentioned originally.  so is there an older version of EasyBCD? or some other way around this?  I still haven't found a way to boot up in ubuntu.

Comment: I don't think EasyBCD will work for a wubi install.

Comment: ok thanks Mike.  so how do I get windows boot manager to come up?

Comment: Well I just wanted to see if a linux based OS was for me and I think I have my answer before I have even seen one in action.  No useful help for the a non technical user like me.